# Can I link to all image files in a directory in Rmd?

Tags: r, r-markdown

I have an R script that produces a number of png files and places them in a subdirectory (called plot). For simplicity, I want to keep this file as a straightforward R script.

I would also like to use an Rmd script to display all the png images in an html or pdf file. I know how to use  to embed individual files, but is it possible to embed rmarkdown in a loop, or another way to include the files? I checked, and  doesn't work.

I have the basis of a chunk to get the file names but I am missing a key line:

```
plots <- list.files("plot/")
for(i in plots){
  # NOW WHAT?
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks.

EDIT

This worked. Thanks @Gregor.

```
plots <- list.files("plot/")
   for(i in plots){
      filename <- file.path("plot", i)
      cat("![text](",filename,")")
    }
```

Comment: The general markdown code for inserting an image is `![Alt text](/path/to/img.jpg)`, so you want to `cat()` that and use the chunk options `results = 'asis'`.

Comment: That fixed it. I have updated the original post with the solution. Thanks.

Comment: Rather than putting the answer inside your question, go ahead a post it as an actual answer. (Answering your own question is encouraged.) After 24 hours you'll be allowed to accept your answer and everything will be nice and orderly. And you might even get some internet points when other people upvote your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

As per the Gregor's comment, the solution is

````
```{r, results = 'asis'}

plots <- list.files("plot/")

for(i in plots){
  filename <- file.path("plot", i)
  cat("![text](",filename,")")
```
````